# ¿Cómo contar las llamadas totales al método de una clase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, clase, método

Imaginen que para un juego se tiene una clase `NaveEspacial` en la que los jugadores tienen la capacidad, entre otras cosas, de cambiar el nombre de la nave luego de haberla creado:

```
class NaveEspacial:
    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan

    def imprimir_datos(self):
        datos = {
            'nombre': self.nombre,
            'capitan': self.capitan
        }
        print datos

    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre

nave = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave.imprimir_datos()

# Resultado
{'nombre': 'Death Star', 'capitan': 'Cesitar'}
{'nombre': 'Millennium Falcon', 'capitan': 'Cesitar'}
```

Si quisiera saber cuantas veces se ha cambiado el nombre de la nave, podría agregar un contador:

```
class NaveEspacial:
    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan
        self.total_renombres = 0

    def imprimir_datos(self):
        datos = {
            'nombre': self.nombre,
            'capitan': self.capitan,
            'total_renombres': self.total_renombres
        }
        print datos

    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.total_renombres += 1

nave = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave.imprimir_datos()

# Resultado
{'nombre': 'Death Star', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 0}
{'nombre': 'Millennium Falcon', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 1}
```

Pero lo anterior solo me ayudaría a saber cuantas veces ha sido renombrada cada **instancia** de la clase, es decir, cada nave:

```
nave = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave.imprimir_datos()

nave = NaveEspacial('USS Enterprise', 'Fiorella')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Centaur')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Challenger')
nave.imprimir_datos()

# Resultado
{'nombre': 'Death Star', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 0}
{'nombre': 'Millennium Falcon', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 1}
{'nombre': 'USS Enterprise', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 0}
{'nombre': 'USS Centaur', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 1}
{'nombre': 'USS Challenger', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 2}
```

Lo que necesito es contar las llamadas totales al método de la **clase** y no el total por cada **instancia**. Se que una forma podría ser acumular todas las naves y sumar el atributo `total_renombres` de cada una:

```
naves = [nave1, nave2, nave3]
total = sum([nave.total_renombres for nave in naves])
```

Pero quiero saber si es posible hacer esto a nivel de la clase, como algún tipo de variable persistente durante todo el tiempo de vida del juego. ¿Existe una forma de hacerlo?

---

**Nota:**

Por el momento quiero mantenerlo sencillo y evitar el uso de Bases de Datos.

---

#### Actualización 1 (respuesta de @RuslanLópezCarro)

Es posible conseguir el total creando una variable de la clase, pero eso implicaría tener que incrementar manualmente la variable cada vez que se llama al método `renombrar()`:

```
nave1 = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave1.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
NaveEspacial.total_llamadas += 1 # Incrementar

nave2 = NaveEspacial('USS Enterprise', 'Fiorella')
nave2.renombrar('USS Centaur')
NaveEspacial.total_llamadas += 1 # Incrementar
nave2.renombrar('USS Challenger')
NaveEspacial.total_llamadas += 1 # Incrementar

nave3 = NaveEspacial('ABC', 'Tany')
nave3.renombrar('XYZ')
NaveEspacial.total_llamadas += 1 # Incrementar

print NaveEspacial.total_llamadas 

# Resultado 4
```

Lo cual no me parece una opción, quiero hacerlo de forma automática con cada llamada al método.

Comment: actualicé mi respuesta, pues tenía un error en el decorador. También incluí otro código para contar las invocaciones de más de un método, para que quede para la posteridad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Actualización**:

Acabo de corregir una línea del código que faltaba, haciendo que el decorador no invocase a la función decorada.

También incluyo la manera de contabilizar la invocación de más de un método de la clase.

---

La mejor forma de implementar esto, en mi opinión, es con un `decorador` que maneje la variable estática (agrego comentarios a todos los métodos escritos por mí):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class NaveEspacial:
    total_renombres = 0

    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan

    def imprimir_datos(self):
        datos = {
            'nombre': self.nombre,
            'capitan': self.capitan,
            'total_renombres': NaveEspacial.total_renombres
        }
        print datos

    def _dec_incrementa_renombres(func):
        """Esta es la función decoradora, que se encarga
        de invocar al método de clase _incrementa_contador_renombres.

        El incremento no funciona haciéndolo dentro de la función
        "interno". Ésta última debe invocar al método de clase.
        """
        def interno(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            resultado = func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            cls._incrementa_contador_renombres()
            return resultado
        return interno

    @_dec_incrementa_renombres
    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        """Método decorado con el incremento del contador."""
        self.nombre = nombre

    @classmethod
    def _incrementa_contador_renombres(cls):
        """Es un método de clase que solamente incrementa
        el contador estático.
        """
        cls.total_renombres += 1

nave = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave.imprimir_datos()

nave = NaveEspacial('USS Enterprise', 'Fiorella')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Centaur')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Challenger')
nave.imprimir_datos()
```

La salida de este código es la esperada:

```
{'nombre': 'Death Star', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 0}
{'nombre': 'Millennium Falcon', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 1}
{'nombre': 'USS Enterprise', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 1}
{'nombre': 'USS Centaur', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 2}
{'nombre': 'USS Challenger', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 3}
```

**Por lo tanto, los pasos recomendados son:**

1. Agregar una variable estática con valor inicial `0`.
2. Implementar un método de clase que al ser llamado solamente incremente la variable estática del punto anterior.
3. Implementar un método decorador, cuya función interna simplemente invoque al método de clase del punto anterior.

   - Incrementar el contador en esta función interna no funciona.
4. Finalmente utilizar el decorador anterior para decorar la función cuyas invocaciones deseamos contar.

### ------

**Bonus:**

Para implementar una contabilización de las invocaciones de más de un método, hay que hacer un pequeño cambio a la función decoradora, fundamentalmente para que discierna qué función está decorando, y por lo tanto sepa a qué contador ordenar su incremento:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class NaveEspacial:
    total_renombres = 0
    total_impresiones = 0

    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan

    def _dec_incrementa(func):
        """Esta es la función decoradora que se encarga
        de incrementar el contador que corresponda según la función
        que fue invocada.
        """
        def interno(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            resultado = func(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            if func.__name__ == 'renombrar':
                cls._incrementa_contador_renombres()
            elif func.__name__ == 'imprimir_datos':
                cls._incrementa_contador_impresiones()
            return resultado
        return interno

    @_dec_incrementa
    def imprimir_datos(self):
        datos = {
            'nombre': self.nombre,
            'capitan': self.capitan,
            'total_renombres': NaveEspacial.total_renombres,
            'total_impresiones': NaveEspacial.total_impresiones
        }
        print datos

    @_dec_incrementa
    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        """Método decorado con el incremento del contador."""
        self.nombre = nombre

    @classmethod
    def _incrementa_contador_renombres(cls):
        """Es un método de clase que solamente incrementa
        el contador estático.
        """
        cls.total_renombres += 1

    @classmethod
    def _incrementa_contador_impresiones(cls):
        """Es un método de clase que solamente incrementa
        el contador estático.
        """
        cls.total_impresiones += 1


nave = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave.imprimir_datos()

nave = NaveEspacial('USS Enterprise', 'Fiorella')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Centaur')
nave.imprimir_datos()
nave.renombrar('USS Challenger')
nave.imprimir_datos()
```

Comment: Nicolás, muchas gracias! Funciona perfectamente, ¿qué opinas de la solución que encontré yo?

Comment: El problema que le encuentro a esa solución es que es equivalente a tener una variable estática, y en cada método al que le estés "haciendo seguimiento", tendrás que incrementar la variable respectiva. En todo caso, funciona, lo que es siempre importante. ;)

Comment: En realidad es un **atributo** del metodo el cual solo incremento cuando se llama al mismo. Igual creo que tu solución es mas Pythónica, check para ti y por tu gran solución!

Comment: Creo que esta solución no es correcta. El "contador" de llamadas de realiza a nivel de **clase** `cls.total_renombres += 1` y no de **instancia**, con lo cual todas las instancias de una clase contribuyen al contador.

Answer (score 6):

Declara tu variable dentro de la definición de clase

```
class NaveEspacial:
    total_renombres = 3
```

De esa manera será una variable estática.
Para más información puedes consultar [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python).

Comment: No me está funcionando, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo?  La variable siempre esta igual, la idea es que vaya aumentando con respecto a las instancias creadas y que cada llamada a `renombrar` aumente en 1

Comment: ¿Tengo que llamar manualmente a `NaveEspacial.total_renombres +=1` cada vez que se llama al método? La idea es que sea automático y ocurra cuando se llama el método

Comment: a diferencia de otros lenguajes como Java, hay un acceso de instancia y uno de clase, ambos tienen diferentes valores. Debes de acceder al valor global.

Answer (score 5):

Encontré una forma, un poco más sencilla que la brindada por @Nicolás pero un poco más "oscura" a la vez.

De acuerdo a la documentación sobre los [métodos](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=im_func#methods), es posible asignarles atributos de manera arbtiraria haciendo uso del atributo especial de solo lectura llamado `im_func` proporcionado a los métodos de instancia de las clases.

Esto **no** es posible:

```
>>> class Clase:
...     def metodo(self):
...         pass
...
>>> Clase.metodo.total = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'total'
```

Esto **si** es posible:

```
>>> class Clase:
...     def metodo(self):
...         pass
...
>>> Clase.metodo.im_func.total = 0
>>> Clase.metodo.total
0
>>> # El total se acumula entre las instancias
>>> c1 = Clase()
>>> c1.metodo.im_func.total += 5
>>> c2 = Clase()
>>> c2.metodo.im_func.total += 10
>>> c3 = Clase()
>>> c3.metodo.im_func.total += 15
>>> Clase.metodo.total
30
```

De esta forma es posible definir la clase de esta manera:

```
class NaveEspacial:
    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan
        self.total_renombres = 0

    def imprimir_datos(self):
        datos = {
            'nombre': self.nombre,
            'capitan': self.capitan,
            'total_renombres': self.total_renombres
        }
        print datos

    @classmethod
    def imprimir_total_llamadas(cls):
        total = 0
        if hasattr(cls.renombrar.im_func, 'total_llamadas'):
            total = cls.renombrar.total_llamadas
        print total

    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        # En la primera llamada verificamos que exista el atributo
        if not hasattr(self.renombrar.im_func, 'total_llamadas'):
            self.renombrar.im_func.total_llamadas = 0
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.total_renombres += 1
        self.renombrar.im_func.total_llamadas += 1

NaveEspacial.imprimir_total_llamadas()

nave1 = NaveEspacial('Death Star', 'Cesitar')
nave1.renombrar('Millennium Falcon')
nave1.renombrar('Elysium')
nave1.imprimir_datos()

nave2 = NaveEspacial('USS Enterprise', 'Fiorella')
nave2.renombrar('USS Centaur')
nave2.renombrar('USS Challenger')
nave2.imprimir_datos()

nave3 = NaveEspacial('ABC', 'Tany')
nave3.renombrar('XYZ')
nave3.imprimir_datos()

NaveEspacial.imprimir_total_llamadas()

# Resultado
0
{'nombre': 'Elysium', 'capitan': 'Cesitar', 'total_renombres': 2}
{'nombre': 'USS Challenger', 'capitan': 'Fiorella', 'total_renombres': 2}
{'nombre': 'XYZ', 'capitan': 'Tany', 'total_renombres': 1}
5
```

Y de esta forma pude lograr tener un contador general y uno por cada instancia.

**Nota:**

Acabo de probarlo en Python 3.x y parece que esto no es posible, por lo menos no de la forma descrita en esta respuesta.

Answer (score 5):

La mejor solución es usar *descriptores* como atributos de clase.

El código podría ser algo así:

```
# creación del descriptor
class NumRenombres(object):
    def __init__(self, default = 0):
        self.num = default

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.num

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.num = value

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        pass
```

Para su uso, se crea una instancia y se la asigna a un atributo de la clase `NaveEspacial`:

```
class NaveEspacial(object):
    total_renombres = NumRenombres()

    def renombrar(self):
        self.total_renombres += 1
```

Este código funciona correctamente en casi todas las ocasiones. Aún así, aún cabe la posibilidad de *"machacar"* el atributo de clase con un valor arbitrario (eg: `NaveEspacial.total_renombres = 0`). Si necesitas ocultarlo del todo, usa *"name mangling"*, o sea, renombra el atributo con doble subrayado (eg: `__total_renombres`).

Answer (score 4):

El resto de respuestas ya dan diferentes soluciones para llevar la cuenta de los renombre a partir de la propia clase, pero que una nave tenga que llevar la cuenta de los renombres de todas las naves de la flota espacial no es una buena idea. 
Utilizando diseño orientado a objetos se puede obtener más flexibilidad y permite probar las cosas de forma separada.

Aplicando el principio de *[separación de intereses (separation of concerns)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separaci%C3%B3n_de_intereses)* se puede crea una clase nueva que sea la responsable de llevar la cuenta de las naves y los renombres.

```
class ComandanciaEspacial:
    def __init__(self):
        self.naves_renombradas = 0
        self.naves_totales = 0

    def matricular_nave(self):
        self.naves_totales += 1

    def rematricular_nave(self):
        self.naves_renombradas += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        t = "La flota estelar tiene {} naves, que en total se han renombrado {} veces"
        return t.format(self.naves_totales, self.naves_renombradas

>>> comandancia_rebelde = ComandanciaEspacial()
>>> comandancia_rebelde
La flota estelar tiene 0 naves, que en total se han renombrado 0 veces
```

Para que cada nave se entere de a que comandancia ha de rendir cuentas se le ha de indicar, a esto se le llama *inyección de dependecias*

```
class NaveEspacial:
    def __init__(self, nombre, capitan, comandancia):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.capitan = capitan
        self._comandancia = comandancia
        self._comandancia.matricular_nave()

    def renombrar(self, nuevo_nombre):
        self._comandancia.rematricular_nave()
        self.nombre = nuevo_nombre

    def _repr__(self):
        return "Nave: '{}', capitan: '{}'".format(self.nombre, self.capitan

>>> halcon = NaveEspacial('YT-1300', 'Han Solo', comandancia_rebelde)
>>> halcon
Nave: 'YT-1300', capitan: 'Han Solo'
>>> comandancia_rebelde
La flota estelar tiene 1 naves, que en total se han renombrado 0 veces
```

Al renombrar la nave podemos consultar a la comandancia que naves hay

```
>>> halcon.renombrar('Halcon milenario')
>>> halcon
Nave: 'Halcon milenario', capitan: 'Han Solo'
>>> comandancia_rebelde
La flota estelar tiene 1 naves, que en total se han renombrado 1 veces
```

Si no queremos andar especificando a cada nave a que comandancia ha de rendir cuentas podemos crear una *factoría* que se encargue de *inyectar* esa dependencia directamente y así no tener que especificarlo para todas las naves:

```
class AstilleroEspacial:
    def __init__(self, comandancia):
        self._comandancia = comandancia

    def nueva_nave(self, nombre_nave, capitan):
        nave = NaveEspacial(nombre_nave, capitan, self._comandancia)
        return nave

>>> hoth = AstilleroEspacial(comandancia_rebelde)

>>> wing = hoth.nueva_nave('X-Wing', 'Luke Skywalker')
>>> wing
Nave: 'X-Wing', capitan: 'Luke Skywalker'

>>> comandancia_rebelde
La flota estelar tiene 2 naves, que en total se han renombrado 1 veces
```

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión una de las mejores soluciones pasa por combinar conceptos expuestos en las otras respuestas en el caso de querer aplicarla a métodos concretos de una clase.

- Utilizando un `descriptor` para decorar el método (que durante la decoración todavía es función) para controlar el accesso (get/set) al atributo
- Utilizando una clase auxiliar para envolver a la función convertida en método y controlar las llamadas al método
- Utilizando el acceso al descriptor a nivel de clase, para poder acceder a sus métodos (como p.ej el que devuelve el número de renombrados)

De esta manera:

- Podemos llevar la cuenta por clase
- Evitamos que el atributo sea sobre-escribible a nivel de instancia (a nivel de clase lo es)

Código:

```py
import collections


class MethodCounter(object):
    class CounterHelper(object):
        def __init__(self, parent, method):
            self.parent = parent
            self.method = method

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.parent.increase(self.method)
            return self.method(*args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
        self.func = func
        self.cache = dict()

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        raise AttributeError('No se puede modificar')

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if obj is None:
            return self

        try:
            return self.cache[obj]
        except KeyError:
            method = self.func.__get__(obj, cls)
            ch = self.__class__.CounterHelper(self, method)
            self.cache[obj] = ch
            return ch

    def increase(self, method):
        try:
            obj = method.im_self  # Py2
        except:
            obj = method.__self__  # Py3

        self.counter[obj] += 1

    def count(self, obj):
        return self.counter[obj]


class Nave(object):
    def __init__(self, nombre='Nombre'):
        self.nombre = nombre

    @MethodCounter
    def renombrar(self, nombre):
        print('renombrando')
        self.nombre = nombre


nave = Nave('Halcon')
nave.renombrar('Milenario')
print('Renombrados nave:', Nave.renombrar.count(nave))

nave2 = Nave('Estrella')
nave2.renombrar('De la')
nave2.renombrar('Muerte')

print('Renombrados nave:', Nave.renombrar.count(nave))
print('Renombrados nave2:', Nave.renombrar.count(nave2))

try:
    nave.renombrar = 3
except AttributeError:
    print('No se puede modificar el método en una instancia')

Nave.renombrar = 5
print('Siempre se puede modificar el atributo a nivel de clase')
```

Resultado:

```
renombrando
Renombrados nave: 1
renombrando
renombrando
Renombrados nave: 1
Renombrados nave2: 2
No se puede modificar el método en una instancia
Siempre se puede modificar el atributo a nivel de clase
```